# server client sending receiving structure via raw data errors C++

Tags: c++, server, client, winsock, raw-data

I am doing a sending and receiving functions for structure(in my case "frame") via TCP/IP. But the functions don't seem to work out and I cannot find where my errors are. I am asked to store all the data in a char array and send it, while receiving the char array and convert them into the structure.

```
struct frame {
int length;
int * body;
int tail;
};


void winsock_client::send_frame(frame f) {
    char * arr;
    char * tx;
    int length = 8 + f.length * sizeof(int);
    arr = new char[length];

    tx = (char*)&f.length; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
        arr[i] = *(tx++);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        tx =(char*)&f.body[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++) {
            arr[4 + i * sizeof(int) + j] = *(tx++);
        }
    }

        tx = (char*)&f.tail;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
        arr[4 + f.length * sizeof(int) + i] = *(tx++);
    }

    send(client_socket, arr, sizeof(arr), 0);
}


void winsock_server::receive_frame(frame & f) {
int * rx;
recv(server_socket, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer), 0);
rx =(int *) &rx_buffer[0];
f.length = *rx;

f.body = new int[f.length];

rx = (int *)&rx_buffer[4];
for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    f.body[i] = *(rx++);
}

rx = (int*)&rx_buffer[16];
f.tail = *rx;

}
```

Can anyone tell me what my errors are in my functions?

Comment: `int length = 8 + f.length * sizeof(int);` -- What makes you sure that the two `int` members equal 8 bytes?  [Look at this example that shows that sizeof(frame) == 24](https://ideone.com/NElHJM).

Comment: Rember that TCP is a stream of data. In any given packet or call to `recv` you may or may not get all of the data you asked for. For example when you read for a `Frame` you may not get a whole `Frame`. Check the return value and keep looping until you have it all or use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to block until everything has arrived.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` in `send_frame()` does not return what you think it does.

Comment: Yeah, I have changed sizeof(arr) to length instead. Still not working

Comment: @AndyLin -- Why not simply inspect via debugging exactly what you're sending?  Is what you're sending look correct?  You're putting this data together, where do you do any sort of debugging to ensure you're not sending garbage or totally wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the return values of `send()` and `recv()` to make sure that you are actually sending/receiving everything you are expecting.  TCP is a streaming transport, there is no 1:1 relationship between sends and receives, like there is in UDP.  Both functions can send/receive fewer bytes than requested, so you need to handle that.

Also, your `read_frame()` is using a fixed-length buffer to receive data, but you aren't taking into account how much data is actually being sent, so your buffer may not receive a full frame, or worse may receive a frame that is larger than it can hold.

The code is just plain ugly to read, too.  It should be be re-written.

Try something more like this instead:

```
bool sendAll(SOCKET s, const void *buf, int len)
{
    const char *pbuf = (const char*) buf;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(s, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return false;
        pbuf += sent;
        len -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool winsock_client::send_frame(const frame &f)
{
    int size = (2 + f.length) * sizeof(u_long);

    char *arr = new char[size];

    // multi-byte integers should always be transmitted in network
    // byte order to avoid any endian issues across machine boundaries...

    u_long *ptr = (u_long*) arr;

    *ptr++ = htonl(f.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
        *ptr++ = htonl(f.body[i]);

    *ptr = htonl(f.tail);

    bool result = sendAll(client_socket, arr, size);

    delete[] arr;

    return result;
}
```

```
bool recvAll(SOCKET s, void *buf, int len)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int recvd = recv(s, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0) // -1 on error, 0 on disconnect
            return false;
        pbuf += recvd;
        len -= recvd;
    }
    return true;
}

bool winsock_server::receive_frame(frame &f)
{
    u_long temp;

    if (!recvAll(server_socket, &temp, sizeof(temp)))
        return false;
    f.length = ntohl(temp);

    u_long *arr = new u_long[f.length+1];

    if (!recvAll(server_socket, arr, sizeof(u_long) * (f.length + 1)))
    {
        delete[] arr;
        return false;
    }

    f.body = new int[f.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
        f.body[i] = ntohl(arr[i]);

    f.tail = ntohl(arr[f.length]);

    delete[] arr;

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the code a bit if you take into account that the socket already does its own internal buffering for you:

```
bool sendAll(SOCKET s, const void *buf, int len)
{
    const char *pbuf = (const char*) buf;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int sent = send(s, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return false;
        pbuf += sent;
        len -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendInt(SOCKET s, int value)
{
    // multi-byte integers should always be transmitted in network
    // byte order to avoid any endian issues across machine boundaries...
    u_long temp = htonl(value);
    return sendAll(s, &temp, sizeof(temp));
}

bool winsock_client::send_frame(const frame &f)
{
    if (!sendInt(client_socket, f.length))
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
    {
        if (!sendInt(client_socket, f.body[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return sendInt(client_socket, f.tail);
}
```

```
bool recvAll(SOCKET s, void *buf, int len)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int recvd = recv(s, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0) // -1 on error, 0 on disconnect
            return false;
        pbuf += recvd;
        len -= recvd;
    }
    return true;
}

bool recvInt(SOCKET s, int &value)
{
    u_long temp;
    bool result = recvAll(s, &temp, sizeof(temp));
    if (result) value = ntohl(temp);
    return result;
}

bool winsock_server::receive_frame(frame &f)
{
    if (!recvInt(server_socket, f.length))
        return false;

    f.body = new int[f.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i)
    {
        if (!recvInt(server_socket, f.body[i]))
        {
            delete[] f.body;
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!recvInt(server_socket, f.tail))
    {
        delete[] f.body;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```